# how to display the number of letters in alphabet in label while typing in the textbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that whenever you type a letter in the textbox the number of the letter in alphabet would appear in the label......
I've tried some codes like this:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userInput = textBox1.Text;
            char charCount;
            charCount = userInput[0];

            label1 = charCount.Length.ToString();
        }
```

But I can't find my solution for my problem.....

I'll appreciate the help I can get....

Comment: `label1.Text = textBox1.Text.Lengrh.ToString();`  displays the input length not 'alphabet length' and assuming `label1` is a Winforms label

Comment: It's always 26, no matter which letter you type.

Comment: You want number of  last letter like A == 1, B == 2 ... Z == 26?

Comment: ^ Yes I want an output like that......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show letter position in alphabet.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userInput = textBox1.Text;            //get string from textbox
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput)) return;  //return if string is empty
    char c = char.ToUpper(userInput[userInput.Length - 1]); //get last char of string and normalize it to big letter
    int alPos = c-'A'+1;                         //subtract from char first alphabet letter

    label1 = alPos.ToString();                   //print/show letter position in alphabet
}
```

Comment: Hey Logman, thanks for the help! Its really helpful for my project!

Comment: @JanChristopherSantos glad to help. If you are satisfy with my answer please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to find an event, that is triggered, when you text in the textbox is changed. For example KeyUp. Then you need to register a function to it by using code like this.

```
your_textbox.KeyUp += your_textbox_KeyUp;
```

Visual Studio will help you by creating an empty function.

The function should look like this:

```
private void your_textbox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    your_label.Content = your_textbox.Text.Length.ToString();
}
```

your_label.Content is the Property that will be displayed in the label and the term on the right will get the length of the text in your textbox.

If you want the label not only to say the number, but wrap it in a text, use String.Format like this:

```
your_label.Content = String.Format("The text is {0} characters long", your_textbox.Text.Length);
```

My answer is aiming for WPF though. If you are using WinForms some keywords might be different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want only the number of letters (alphabet) written in the textbox, here's a simple code :

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (char c in textbox.Text)
    {
        int ascii = (int)c;
        if ((ascii >= 97 && <= 122) || (ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90)) // a to z or A to Z
            i++;
    }

    label1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

More simple code :

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (char c in textbox.Text)
        if (char.IsLetter(c))
            i++;

    label1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the number of distinct letters in the textbox, you could use:

```
textbox.Text.ToUpper().Where(char.IsLetter).Distinct().Count();
```